# Optimal Vertex Cover in Z3/Java

Tags: z3

How to encode the optimal vertex cover problem below in Z3/Java?
In particular, how to express the minimize condition?
I could not find a similar example in the Z3/Java examples.

```
(declare-fun vertex_a () Bool)
(declare-fun vertex_b () Bool)
(declare-fun vertex_c () Bool)
(declare-fun vertex_d () Bool)
(declare-fun vertex_e () Bool)
(declare-fun edge_a_c () Bool)
(declare-fun edge_a_b () Bool)
(declare-fun edge_a_e () Bool)
(declare-fun edge_b_c () Bool)
(declare-fun edge_b_d () Bool)
(declare-fun edge_b_e () Bool)
(assert edge_a_c)
(assert edge_a_b)
(assert edge_a_e)
(assert edge_b_c)
(assert edge_b_d)
(assert edge_b_e)
(assert (=> edge_a_c (or vertex_a vertex_c)))
(assert (=> edge_a_b (or vertex_a vertex_b)))
(assert (=> edge_a_e (or vertex_a vertex_e)))
(assert (=> edge_b_c (or vertex_b vertex_c)))
(assert (=> edge_b_d (or vertex_b vertex_d)))
(assert (=> edge_b_e (or vertex_b vertex_e)))
(minimize (+ (if vertex_a 1 0) (if vertex_b 1 0) (if vertex_c 1 0) (if vertex_d 1 0) (if vertex_e 1 0)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (see relevant part below).
No solver is needed but instead an `Optimize` is used.
The `property` contains the implications and the the `minimize_expr` contains the sum over the "true" vertices.
For other examples, I had to also remove the term `(if vertex_X 1 0)` for unconnected vertices from `minimize_expr`.

```
        Optimize optimize = context.mkOptimize();
        optimize.Add(property);
        optimize.MkMinimize(minimize_expr);
        optimize.Check();
        Model model = optimize.getModel();
```